# Efficiently get largest 3 integers in C++ Linked List (unsorted)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I heard there were some std functions that do give the largest n integers of an array, but how about a linked list?

I would think a solution would be to have a few for loops to iterate over the linked list, but it seems as if there could be a simpler solution in the C++ libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb: virtually nothing is really efficient with linked lists.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this if you can't use another data structure:

```
typedef std::list<int> IntList;
InstList list = <your_values>;

int top[3];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    top[i] = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

IntList::iterator it, end;
for (it = list.begin(), end = list.end(); it != end; ++it) {
    const int& value = *it;
    if (value > top[2]) {
        top[0] = top[1];
        top[1] = top[2];
        top[2] = value;
    } else if (value > top[1]) {
        top[0] = top[1];
        top[1] = value;
    } else if (value > top[0]) {
        top[0] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look into using a [`priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/).

Comment: If he's going to entirely switch data structures anyway, he may as well use `std::vector<>` + `std::partial_sort`. That said, the question is quite specifically about using a linked list...

Comment: I'm required to keep a linked list, but I have a void function that I can probably just copy the elements into a std::vector<>

Comment: I think Jorge was hinting at a solution similar to mine.  I don't think he was suggesting that you change your data structure.

Comment: @ildjarn: For this, `nth_element` is probably better than `partial_sort` (and given that you're going to copy anyway, might as well use `partial_sort_copy`).

Comment: @Jerry : Good call on `nth_element`. :-]

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to maintain a sorted list, priority queue, or heap of exactly `N` numbers.  You push the first `N` values of your list into that, then you iterate through the remainder.  If you encounter item that is larger than the smallest value in your queue (or whatever), you remove that element and push the new one in.

If you're only looking for `N=3`, then using a simple array is probably better than a priority queue or anything else.  You can determine which element in that array is the minimum with just two comparisons.  You always remember the index of the minimum element, and only update that when you replace it.

Interestingly, this approach would have the worst performance for a list that is sorted in ascending order.  However, it is still essentially linear time complexity.